# Subfigures in subfigures in latex

Tags: subfloats

I'm trying to put two separate images in one subfigure so that it can be combined with another one to complete a figure i.e.

```
(img-a) (img-b)     (img-c) (img-d)
      (a)                 (b)
        Figure 1: A caption
```

I've tried several methods but they never seem to work. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no limit on the number of images you can put in a `subcaption` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}

\caption{}
\end{subfigure}\quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}

\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was using the `subfig` package with `subcaption` and this may have brought about problems.

Comment: @JoshuaAduol Without an example of your setup, it's difficult to give more advice.